# Reactive 4.2.0 .Net

Tags: reactive

Is there a difference between Concat and Zip in regards to the lazy/eager evaluation of timer or delay IObservable objects within the sequence?

If I Concat a sequence with Observable.Delay in it, does Concat subscribe to this sequence and eagerly evaluate it, forcing a hard delay in the evaluation of even the first element of the subsequent sequence?

Does Zip behave similarly?  Will Zip eagerly evaluate each Delay Observable within the sequence, and force a hard delay in the triggering of the Observable Delay object - paired element in the merging sequence?

Should these operators do this? Should Zip return an unevaluated, but 'deferred' pairing that can then be subscribed to? Should Concat?!?

Related:

"The third and fourth overloads allow to you merge sequences that can be evaluated lazily at run time. The Merge operators that take a sequence of sequences make for an interesting concept. You can either pull or be pushed observable sequences, which will be subscribed to immediately. "

http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#CombiningMultipleSequences

Comment: What do you mean by "forcing a hard delay in the evaluation of even the first element of the subsequent sequence"? And "Should Zip return an unevaluated, but 'deferred' pairing that can then be subscribed to?" I just don't understand what you're saying. Can you provide code that explains?

Comment: @Enigmativity ok let me work on that.  Can you start from that quote from introtorx and show me an example of how a sequence of sequences (possibly with timers inside) could be 'pushed' **and** 'pulled'?

Comment: The idea of pushing or pulling a sequence of observables comes directly from the signatures. If you have either `IEnumerable<IObservable<TSource>> sources` or `IObservable<TSource>[] sources` then you are able to pull observable sequences. If you have `IObservable<IObservable<TSource>> sources` then those observable sequences are being pushed to you.

Comment: The idea of "possibly with timers inside" is irrelevant to the `Merge` operator - it doesn't care how the inner observables are defined.

Comment: I think I have a better understanding of your question now. All operators work on the observables past thru and they respect the delays inherent in them - they just don't care how the inner observable is defined.

Comment: @Enigmativity So IObservable of IObservable actually has an extension method defined to call Concat.  So it flattens the sequences of sequences into one sequence - does it subscribe and respect the delays in the inner sequences? Or it is only 'observing' the outer Sequence headers?

Comment: I don't know what `Or it is only 'observing' the outer Sequence headers?` means. But, an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` gets flattened to a `IObservable<T>` by joining each inner observable on to the previous one - which means each inner observable must complete with `OnCompleted`. Any delays are "respected" - but I mean this in that `Concat` knows nothing of any delays so it can't affect the inner observables. Why don't you just try an example and see?

Comment: @Enigmativity Ok, I'm working on the examples.  I hesitate to do that as I 'm not sure the .NET implementation conforms to the de facto standard.  Anyway, so Concat can know that the sequence completes, knows that there are no exceptions or infinite loops in the inner sequence, but it doesn't have to actually subscribe to each element to find that out?

Comment: I don't know what ".NET implementation conforms to the de facto standard" means. What de facto standard?

Comment: `Concat` only knows when each inner observable completes when it completes with `OnCompleted`. It only subscribes to the next inner observable when the previous one completes. If there are any errors the `Concat` operator also errors and stops at that point.

Comment: @Enigmativity So Zip does the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "does the same thing"?

Comment: @Enigmativity According to the article, there is an overload of Merge which "will be subscribed to immediately".  Is this the way Zip operates when it Zips each pair? Does the other overload of Merge not work the same way, that subsequences "will be subscribed to immediately"

Comment: `Zip` must immediately subscribe to both in order to zip the values. `Merge` must subscribe as soon as possible to all observables to be able to merge. That's the only way that they can work.

Comment: @Enigmativity "Concat knows nothing of any delays so it can't affect the inner observables". Do you maintain this assertion and can you categorically separate it's modus operandi from Merge and Zip

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to get at. `Concat` and `Merge` and `Zip` cannot affect their inner observables.